# Can a poltergeist use a wand to cast magic?

Tags: harry-potter

As described in [the Pottermore entry for Peeves](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/peeves), a poltergeist can interact with the physical world:

> The name 'poltergeist' is German in origin, and roughly translates as 'noisy ghost', although it is not, strictly speaking, a ghost at all. The poltergeist is an invisible entity that moves objects, slams doors and creates other audible, kinetic disturbances.

Since a poltergeist can move objects, they can obviously move a wand. Could they actually cast a spell with it?

<sub>Note that a poltergeist is different than a ghost in the Wizarding World. See [What are the differences between a ghoul, a ghost and a poltergeist?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114445/13217)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Probably not.**

To say the least, Peeves is not particularly respectful of authority, and resides in a castle full of people with wands, including first and second years with little ability to fend off Peeves' attacks.  It would not have been difficult for him to get hold of one.

Therefore, if he could use a wand to make his "little jokes" more impressive, he undoubtedly would have.  *Frequently.*

(Such incidents would certainly have been worth including in the books, so in this case absence of evidence really is evidence of absence.  But if anyone can find any more direct evidence one way or the other in canon, I'll delete this answer.)

Comment: Also, it requires at least some basic knowledge to cast magic - the first-years are barely able to do anything meaningful at all. Peeves lacks the discipline to learn spells with wands - so even if he theoretically could wave the wand and say the words, I doubt that something would actually happen.